# JQueryUI: automatically add .accordion(); functionality to any new elements with class="accordion"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the JQuery-UI Accordion, but I'm trying to find a way to not have to initialize it any time any new element is added.  Using AJAX I'm inserting html into a page, but on any page load I am having to re-initialize any accordions-

```
// .ajax handler
success: function(xml) {

    // find accordions
    $("div.accordion").accordion();

}
```

Is there any way I can automatically have this run any time the DOM has changed?  I know there is the livequery plugin -- but is there a simpler more elegant method?

Comment: I don't think you want to run this /any time/ the DOM has changed... that happens a lot. Why can't you call accordion() on the HTML you're inserting while you're still inside your success handler?

Comment: that's actually what I'm doing now -- $('div.accordion', context);  There is a bunch of user content that is going into a content area -- however, I want to find a simple solution since there are going to be lots of calls to jquery-ui elements -- which means I have to add a new jquery call for each element.  Maybe there's a faster method than using html classes?  Possibly a rel="" link or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up going with a different approach and tying functionality to mapped strings.  I now use one attribute for everything .  I do a find() based upon that and load it with it's associated value.

pseudo: `$(this)[$(this).attr('ui:component')]();`

Answer (score 0):

Someone may be able to provide more information, but I'm running into a similar situation. As far as I can tell, you have to dynamically apply the accordion based upon the changed DOM. You could just use the [.live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and have it run on load. Something like this has worked for me.

```
$('div.accordion').live('load', accordion());
```

See if that helps you.

Comment: According to the jQuery docs, that shouldn't work: `load` is only fires for elements with a URL (e.g. images, iframes). I'm curious if and why this works.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work on items added to the DOM.  You would think there would be an event for html or domchange.

Comment: @Daniel - Yeah, that would be useful. I've needed something like that few times. @kevingessner - I'm going from memory...it may have been 'ready'. Either way, this situation isn't exactly the same, but it was similar, so I figured I'd post about it.